# gtfファイルの読み込みで ”R Session Aborted" 、RNA-seqデータ解析

Tags: r, bioinformatics

R初心者でゲノム発現解析を始めました。
環境：MacOS、メモリ32GB使用、R version 4.0.0、Rtudio利用

HiSeqで解析したRNA-seq readカウント後のデータで、geneIDをgeneSymbolにするため、RパッケージrefGenomeを使用。
DAVIDでうまく変換できなかったりと他にも色々試しました。

アノテーションのgtfファイル(1.46G)を開いたところ、以下のコメントで終了してしまいました。

```
R Session Aborted, R encounters a fatal error. The session was terminated
```

コード

```
library(refGenome)
gtf = ensemblGenome()
read.gtf(gtf, filename="xxx.gtf")
```

Rコンソールでも同様の結果です。メモリが足りないのでしょうか？
どなたか解決法や他の方法などご教示いただけると助かります。

Comment: R 3.6.3/refGenome 1.7.7 で 1.5 GB(6,500,000 lines)の GTF ファイルを読み込んでみましたが、エラーは発生しませんでした。また、読み込みが完了した時点での R プロセスの使用メモリ量(RSS)は 6.3GB です。原因としては、読み込み対象の GTF ファイルが部分的に欠損している(corrpution)か、GTF format としては illegal などが考えられます。

Comment: metropolisさん：ご助言と丁寧なご説明をありがとうございます！大変参考になります。GTF ファイルの再ダウンロードをしたのですが、通信制限がかかっているようで(連休中問題なくできました)、中断されてしまいました。別のIT環境とPCになりますがまたやってみます。気になる点といえば、先程DeSeqを行い、rtracklayer、XVectorを使って同じgtfファイルを読み込んでみたのですが、問題なくgeneIDとgeneSymbolがリンクできていました（スクリプトを写経させていただいてます）。勉強中なので機会があれば、またお願いいたします。

Comment: GTFファイルを再ダウンロードして試してみましたが、上記と同じ現象がおきました。RパッケージのrtracklayerでGTFファイルを開けましたのでお知らせします。

Answer (score 0):

以前同じ現象が起きましたが，再起動したり　再インストールし直したらあっさりうまくいきました．一応試してみては？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。再インストールはまだ試していないので今度やってみます。